# Modifying function fails to print expected result

Tags: java

Chao, I would like to modify a variable then get its value after the modifying function but why I get unexpected result.

```
String value="I miss the messenger";
public void func(String value)
{
   value.replace("miss","kiss");
}
/// print it
Writeline(value);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Java strings are *[immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)*, hence `replace` creates a new string which must be assigned, e.g.,

```
value = value.replace("miss", "kiss");
```

Comment: You typoed and ment "immutable"!

Answer (score 3):

The string you pass isn't modified (Strings are immutable in Java).
Thus the `replace(...)` method will return a modified version of the original string, which you will have to pass around, otherwise it gets lost.

Change it to:

```
public String func(String value)
{
  return value.replace("miss","kiss");
}

String value="I miss the messenger";
value = func(value);
Writeline(value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function should return a string and you should printoiut what`s return

```
public String func(String value)
{
  return value.replace("miss","kiss");
}

String value="I miss the messenger";

/// print it
Writeline(func(value));
```